# Regex quotation without quotation marks

Tags: php, regex

I have a very nice regex, which selects quotations from text:

```
(["']).+?\1
```

But I need a regex which selects quotations from text without the quotation marks.

For example, I have:

> The whales comprise eight extant families: "Balaenopteridae" (the rorquals), "Balaenidae" (right whales), "Cetotheriidae" (the pygmy right whale), "Eschrichtiidae" (the gray whale), "Monodontidae" (belugas and narwhals), "Physeteridae" (the sperm whale), ...

I need to extract texts between quotation marks:

> Balaenopteridae, Balaenidae, Cetotheriidae, ...

To extract texts between brackets I use regex: `(?<=\().+?(?=\))`.  It works great, but similar regex for quotation marks does not work. I want use the regex in php.

I tried to use this:

```
(?<=(["'])).+?(?=\1)
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "a regex which selects quotations from text without the quotation marks"? How can you identify a quotation if it's not in quotes?  Also what tool are you using?

Comment: For example, I have: 
_The whales comprise eight extant families: "Balaenopteridae" (the rorquals), "Balaenidae" (right whales), "Cetotheriidae" (the pygmy right whale), "Eschrichtiidae" (the gray whale), "Monodontidae" (belugas and narwhals), "Physeteridae" (the sperm whale), ..._ I need extract texts between quotation marks: Balaenopteridae, Balaenidae, Cetotheriidae, … To extract texts between brackets I use regex: `(?<=\().+?(?=\))` It works great, but similar regex for quotation marks does not work. I want use the regex in php.

Comment: If you use the [tag:php] tag, PHP gurus will flock to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(["'])(.+?)\1
```

Then just get the value for the second group.

Comment: Good idea :) Thanks!